# Paypal : POST data empty after make payment and redirect successful page

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I have a problem regarding the PayPal payment after successfully paid my POST data value is empty. When I change the cmd = `_xclick` to `_notify-validate`. It shows `INVALID`.

Comment: Need more description..

Comment: Please share the code